# regarding Xpath

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I have the following XML:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:axis="http://ws.apache.org/axis2">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <axis:ErrorQueueInput>
         <errorStr>JIRA Topic</errorStr>
         <InputMessage> <a>jira message</a><b>jira2 msg</b> </InputMessage>
      </axis:ErrorQueueInput>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

where I need to get the output as:

```
<a>jira message</a><b>jira2 msg</b>
```

If I keep my XPath like;

```
//soapenv1:Envelope/soapenv1:Body/axis:ErrorQueueInput/InputMessage
```

output is something like:

```
jira message jira2 msg
```

If I try like this:

```
 //soapenv1:Envelope/soapenv1:Body/axis:ErrorQueueInput/InputMessage//child::*
```

output is (which is wrong):

```
 jira message
```

How can I get whole XML (i.e.: `<a>jira message</a><b>jira2 msg</b>`) as my output?

Comment: How are you evaluating the XPath?

Comment: like this;(using xslt) <xsl:value-of select="//axis:ErrorQueueInput/InputMessage//child::*" />

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whatever you are using to evaluate the xpath is coercing the node value to a string. Since you don't say what you are *currently* doing, we can't tell you what is wrong.

On the off chance you are using XSL, possibly you are using `value-of` when you should be using `copy-of`.

Comment: im using xslt; code is; <xsl:value-of select="//axis:ErrorQueueInput/InputMessage//child::*" />       can you correct this?